# print out the shape of each layer in the net architecture

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras

In Keras, we can define the network as follows. Are there any way to output the shape after each layer. For instance, I want to print out the shape of `inputs` after the line defining `inputs`, then print out the shape of `conv1` after the line defining `conv1`, etc.

```
inputs = Input((1, img_rows, img_cols))
conv1 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', init='lecun_uniform', W_constraint=maxnorm(3), border_mode='same')(inputs)
conv1 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', init='lecun_uniform', W_constraint=maxnorm(3), border_mode='same')(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

conv2 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', init='lecun_uniform', W_constraint=maxnorm(3), border_mode='same')(pool1)
conv2 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', init='lecun_uniform', W_constraint=maxnorm(3), border_mode='same')(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a layer has a single node (i.e. if it isn't a shared layer), you can get its input tensor, output tensor, input shape and output shape via: `layer.input_shape`

```
from keras.utils.layer_utils import layer_from_config

config = layer.get_config()
layer = layer_from_config(config)
```

Source: https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/

May be this the easiest way to do:

```
model.layers[layer_of_interest_index].output_shape
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to use it? For instance, I would like to print out the information of pool1.  I tried config = pool1.get_config(), it did not work.

Answer (score 13):

Just using `model.summary()`, which gives you pretty print.

Answer (score 1):

To print the complete model and all of its dependencies you can also look here: https://keras.io/visualization/

I used this command to save my model visualization as a png:

```
from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot
plot(model, to_file='model.png')
```

If you only want to print the layer shape you can do something like this:

```
layer = model.layers[-1]
print(layer.output._keras_shape)
```

Prints: (None, 1, 224, 224) # Nr. Filters, Channels, x_dim, y_dim

Comment: Thanks. If I only want to print out a specific layer, i.e., pool1, how to do that?

Comment: Easisest way is to name the layer and then find it with model.get_layer('pool1').