# Print summary of layer shapes for every layer in Tensorflow network

Tags: python, tensorflow

I like to print every layer's shape at Tensorflow network after feeding input image tensors to the network.
At keras, it can be done as discussed in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733984/print-out-the-shape-of-each-layer-in-the-net-architecture/40735009) or model.summary().

My network is as follows.

```
def basenet(inputs, fatness = 64, dilation = True):
    """
    backbone net of vgg16
    """
    # End_points collect relevant activations for external use.
    end_points = {}
    # Original VGG-16 blocks.
    with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.max_pool2d], padding='SAME'):
        # Block1
        net = slim.repeat(inputs, 2, slim.conv2d, fatness, [3, 3], scope='conv1')
        end_points['conv1_2'] = net
        net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], scope='pool1')
        end_points['pool1'] = net


        # Block 2.
        net = slim.repeat(net, 2, slim.conv2d, fatness * 2, [3, 3], scope='conv2')
        end_points['conv2_2'] = net
        net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], scope='pool2')
        end_points['pool2'] = net


        # Block 3.
        net = slim.repeat(net, 3, slim.conv2d, fatness * 4, [3, 3], scope='conv3')
        end_points['conv3_3'] = net
        net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], scope='pool3')
        end_points['pool3'] = net

        # Block 4.
        net = slim.repeat(net, 3, slim.conv2d, fatness * 8, [3, 3], scope='conv4')
        end_points['conv4_3'] = net
        net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], scope='pool4')
        end_points['pool4'] = net

        # Block 5.
        net = slim.repeat(net, 3, slim.conv2d, fatness * 8, [3, 3], scope='conv5')
        end_points['conv5_3'] = net
        net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [3, 3], 1, scope='pool5')
        end_points['pool5'] = net

        # fc6 as conv, dilation is added
        if dilation:
            net = slim.conv2d(net, fatness * 16, [3, 3], rate=6, scope='fc6')
        else:
            net = slim.conv2d(net, fatness * 16, [3, 3], scope='fc6')
        end_points['fc6'] = net

        # fc7 as conv
        net = slim.conv2d(net, fatness * 16, [1, 1], scope='fc7')
        end_points['fc7'] = net
        #model_summary()
        #from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot
        #plot(model, to_file='model.png')
    return net, end_points;
```

I checked at eventfile with Tensorboard, it has complex graph with other activities, I can't see layer dimensions. I like to see just layer shapes.

How can I do in Tensorflow.

Comment: Maybe try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560313/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-something-like-keras-model-summary-in-tensorflow

Comment: Thanks I have found that before. Discussion using slim is useful for number of variables calculation. But not for layer sizes.

Comment: I used a bit tedious way. Tensorflow should have some decent api rather than using Tensorboard. What I did was running through the net and print the layer shape layer by layer.